# Came jmsComponent: what's the difference setting the exception Listener in different beans?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I set up a jms component with spring like this way:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>
<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="exceptionListener"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConfig"
      class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>

</bean>
```

I notice that all these 4 beans have exceptionListener property. So I wonder what's the difference setting exceptionListener in different beans.

During my test, only setting in CachingConnectionFactory can work, it can go into my ExceptionListener, while in other cases, the exception will be logged somewhere else, but can't go into my code, the exception is like below.

```
WARN CachingConnectionFactory.onException(322)    - Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1983)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:2002)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:126)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:160)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onException(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:314)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.onException(TransportSupport.java:96)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:200)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:275)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:221)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:213)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
    ... 1 more
```

I can't understand how this works, please give some explanation or hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.exceptionListener` set the `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.exceptionListener` , so this is the same.

`org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.exceptionListener` set up the `org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.exceptionListener`

> Set the JMS ExceptionListener to notify in case of a JMSException
>   thrown by the registered message listener or the invocation infrastructure.

so it is nearly the same use of that listener at any level but it is better to set it at the `org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.exceptionListener` level to be managed by the spring Container.